# How to set value of checkbox when checked and unchecked using ajax or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I need to get the value of the checkboxes when checked and unchecked and save it in database. The value is 1 if checked and 0 if unchecked, respectively. I am currently using the snippet below and it show the result i want when i alert it. But the problem comes when saving in the database. It still gets the value I have set in my checkbox E.G: value='1'.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        var val = this.type == "checkbox" ? +this.checked : this.value ;            
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="one_by_one" id="one_by_one" class="one_by_one">One
```

Comment: How are you saving it to your database?

Comment: @j08691 I was using an html form in codeigniter. So when i press save button the data will be saved in the mysql database.

Comment: @FelixKling I see. How can i do that in the server side?

Comment: Probably something like `$value = isset($_POST['one_by_one']) ? 1 : 0;`. If you are using codeigniter than it might provide helper functions for accessing the data of a request.

Comment: @FelixKling Is there a way to set it on client side? Jquery perhaps?

Comment: Depends on how the form is submitted. If you use "normal" form submission then no. If you use Ajax then you have a chance to modify the data before you are sending it to the server.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes. I am using ajax in sending data to database. How can i modify it in ajax?

Comment: When you are getting data to send, set the value of `one_by_one` depending on the state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you want this:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    $(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).val("1") : $(this).val("0")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="one_by_one" id="one_by_one" class="one_by_one">One
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does this works for multiple checkboxes?

Comment: Hi. I've tried your code but the value being saved in database is still 1.

Comment: Searched for the solution over the stack. And finalized here!!! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

The value of a checkbox never changes (by itself). If the checkbox is not checked its value simply won't be sent to the server. So at the server side you should check whether `one_by_one` is included in the request and set the value accordingly (e.g. set `0` if it doesn't exist or the value of `one_by_one` if it does).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i set the value accordingly on php? Can you give me some snippet?

Comment: Probably something like `$value = isset($_POST['one_by_one']) ? 1 : 0;`.